# How turn off import auto suggestion in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, volar

Working with Vue and use an auto import plugin, so I don't use `import`.

VSCode keeps injecting `import { watch } from 'less'` in the beginning of a file when I type `watch(`. Then I go debugging...

How can I turn it off? Can't find an appropriate setting.

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim only 'Vue - official'

Comment: I was using Typescript Importer and I was facing this problem then I disabled it, it sets the import statement before `<script setup lang="ts">` :)